# Question Versions using CTE RECURSION MYSQL

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

Problem:
An application for testing programmers contains an initial question version and newer question versions, represented by the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE questions ( 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    childId INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY (childId) REFERENCES questions (id) 
); 

INSERT INTO questions (id, name, childId) 
VALUES 
(3, 'SQL select v3', NULL), 
(2, 'C# tuples', NULL), 
(1, 'SQL select v2', 3), 
(0, 'SQL select', 1);
```

The latest question version has childId set to NULL, other question versions will have childId set to the next version. Each question version can be a child of only one other question version.

Finish the findLatestVersion stored procedure so that it returns the latest question version.

Example case:

```
CALL findLatestVersion(0);
-- Expected output (in any order): 
-- 3
```

I need help to write the code

Comment: -- Example case:
CALL findLatestVersion(0)
-- Expected output (in any order):
-- 3

Comment: Codes are transferred from the comments to the question.

Comment: I think they downvoted, perhaps, because questions should show that you have put some effort into solving it yourself ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ _hope that helps_.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE findLatestVersion (IN question_id INT)
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT id, childId, 1 level
    FROM questions 
    WHERE id = question_id 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT questions.id, questions.childId, cte.level + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN questions ON cte.childId = questions.id
)
SELECT cte.id
FROM cte
ORDER BY level DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, Akina, the code functions very well, but I doubt why when the input question_id =2, the procedure gives the result of 2. I appreciate any help you can provide. :)

Comment: @MilagrosSantos *why when the input question_id =2, the procedure gives the result of 2.* ?? what output you'd like to see for it?

Comment: @milagrosSantos 2 has no children so it is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever...here is a solution that does not use a `cte`, it is debatably easier to groc. I do with the main select statement was not reused, but aside from that stain on the elegance, this solution passes all checks.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE findLatestVersion(
    IN questionId INTEGER
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE qId INTEGER;
    DECLARE qName VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE qChildId INTEGER;

    SELECT id, name, childId
    INTO qId, qName, qChildId
    FROM questions
    WHERE id = questionId;

    IF (qChildId IS NOT NULL) THEN
        WHILE qChildId IS NOT NULL DO
            SELECT id, name, childId
            INTO qId, qName, qChildId
            FROM questions
            WHERE id = qChildId;
        END WHILE;
    END IF

    SELECT qId;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Note that the question from the *dome* that this came from is worded rather funky:

> *findLatestVersion stored procedure so that it returns the latest question version.*

I thought this meant they wanted all columns and fought with this line making all tests fail:

> SELECT qId, qName, qChildId;

Apparently by `question version` they specifically mean `return the id of the latest question version`.